# Fullpage.js call function in a conditional statement

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, fullpage.js

I have code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/unwzq6q6/16/):

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
 
  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){ 
  
  
   if(index == 1){ 
    
       var $squares = $('.grid-container div');

        function imgFade() {

          $squares.removeClass('active')

          //Choose 2 random divs
          var square1 = $squares.eq([Math.floor(Math.random()*$squares.length)]) 
          var square2 = $squares.eq([Math.floor(Math.random()*$squares.length)])

          //Assign active class
          $([square1, square2]).each( function(){
            $(this).addClass('active');
          });

          setTimeout(imgFade, 2000);
        }

        imgFade(); 
      
     } else {
        return false;
      }

 
    
    
    
 }
}); //end fullpage
```

```css
body {margin:0}

section {
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
}

.grid-container {width:100%;}

.grid-container div {
  width:20vw;
  height:33.33vh;
  float:left;
  background: purple;
  opacity: 1;
  border:1px solid white;
  transition: opacity 3s ease;
}

div.active {opacity: 0.5;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.6/jquery.fullpage.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.6/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>
<div id="fullpage">

  <section id="section0" class="section">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="section1" class="section">
    Some stuff
  </section>
  
</div>
```

I am trying to execute a function using Fullpage.js when the index (section) is equal to 1. I want the function to stop or pause when the user scrolls to the next section. When I inspect element, I can see the function is still running when I'm no longer on index 1 (the boxes are still changing color), even though I have the function wrapped in a conditional statement.

So I'd like to know how I can only run the function on the first section (index 1), and stop/pause on the other section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are using a timeout.
You'll have to clear it later on.

Follow this schema:

```
var timeoutId;

$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){   
      if(index === 1){
         timeoutId = setTimeout(imgFade, 2000); // <-- timeoutId assignation
      }
      else{
         clearTimeout(timeoutId);   // <-- this will remove the timeout
      }
   }
});
```

You can even clear it in the `onLeave` function. That will be more precise. If the `nextIndex` is different from 1, then clear it.

var timeoutId;

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){   
      if(index === 1){
         timeoutId = setTimeout(imgFade, 2000); // <-- timeoutId assignation
      }
   },

   onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
      if(nextIndex !== 1){
         clearTimeout(timeoutId);   // <-- this will remove the timeout
      }
   }
});
```